# JQuery Datepicker open at initialization with today´s date set

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using Jquery Datepicker and want to set today's date at initialisation.
That is working properly, but once I open my html page with the datepicker, the current date is in the input field, but the datepicker remain open too. This just happens at the initialisation. Once I select a different date, the datepicker overlay disappears.

I want to know how to make the datepicker disappear at initialisation with today's date set.

[image: Screenshot of how the display looks]

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  autoSize: true,
  nextText: '&rarr;',
  prevText: '&larr;',
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  dayNamesMin: ['SO', 'MO', 'DI', 'MI', 'DO', 'FR', 'SA'],
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "/images/calendar.svg",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
}).datepicker("setDate", "today");
```

```html
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
```

I expect, that after initialisation the datepicker with current date set, the datepicker doesn't show up

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the datepicker you're using? There are several. Also please read this article on how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I´m using this one: https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=000000010000000000000010000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve solved this issue by setting  `$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('display', 'none')`after setDate method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed `display: none` style for modal of datepicker.